# Liferay Portal changing default page

Tags: liferay

I'm developing Liferay Portal project, and when I navigate to `localhost:8080`, it's redirecting to `"localhost:8080/en"`.

I did all localization settings for my language (Turkish), but it didn't work. Basically when I navigate to `localhost:8080`, I want it to redirect to `localhost:8080/tr`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the default language from `en_US` to `tr_TR`. Please add the `portal-ext.properties` to your server level or in `ROOT/WEB-INF/classes` and add the following property.

```
company.default.locale=tr_TR
```

after this, restart the server and it should work. This may not work for the existing User, so, please change the user's default language as well from the Profile.

Comment: Hi Felix , thank you for reply. But it doesn't work. I can see default language > Turkish . I done all changes user profile or portal-ext.properties file but  not worked .

Comment: Do you have the language portlet on the page? what is the default regional language settings on your machine?

Comment: No i don't have language portlet on the page. My home page contains welcome page and login portlet. My default language is Turkish on my machine. When I changed user language in control panel , if user login to system everything is ok.But for guest i still get same problem. localhost:8080 redirect to localhost:8080/en . If regulated  user select remember me option and navigate localhost:8080 , same problem come out

Comment: Also try to add this property in portal-ext.properties and restart the server, this should give tr_TR for the guest user. locale.default.request=true

Comment: Thank you Felix,i tried then no solition. i think it's welded my liferay version(6.0.6). I read and tried  about all of this topic. If  I can solve this problem , I'll write here. Anyway if I don't success ,may be i can modify original language file for english

Comment: I solved problem thanks to Felix. Everthing is my fault because i never try my browser's history. When I clean the history files , language translation for Turkish is completed for all user(guest or user ). For guest user you can do  "company.default.locale=tr_TR " ext file addition. Thank you for your help Felix again.